# Can variable in while loop be gloablly reachable? (in bash)

Tags: bash, shell

I have a code snippet, as follows.

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="tmp_list_filenames"
line_index=0
cat $filename | while read processed_data_filename; do
    line_index=$(($line_index + 1))
    var="haha$line_index"
done
echo "thevar:$var"
```

The output is simply `thevar:`, or `$var` is not raechable outside while loop. Why is it the case here? I also tried replace while codeline with `while [ $line_index -lt 3 ]; do`, as follows,

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="tmp_list_filenames"
line_index=0
while [ $line_index -lt 3 ]; do
    line_index=$(($line_index + 1))
    var="haha$line_index"
done
echo "thevar:$var"
```

Then, it prints `thevar:haha4`. It is very strange to me, can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Classic example of UUOC.  By putting the while loop in a pipeline, it is running in a subprocess.  There is no need for the pipe:

```
while ...; do ...; done < $filename
```

should solve the problem

Comment: +1, completely right. I missed the fact that the pipeline wasn't needed (and then went ahead and also missed the pipeline completely in my "solution").

Answer (score 0):

The variable is not reachable because it is set inside a command which is a pipeline component. The pipeline component executes in its own child process, and so the changes in process state such as variable bindings and assignments, is confined to that process, even if the variables in question are global.

You can get values out of a child process if you can get it to print their values in the form of a (carefully escaped) variable assignment, which the shell can then `eval`. (In a situation where you can't just restructure the program to get rid of the sub=process.)

Example:

```
eval $(command 1 | FOO=abc ; echo FOO=\"$FOO\")
#                                         ^^ note: not "carefully escaped"
```

The child prints `FOO="abc"` which the parent will `eval`, thereby setting up a copy of `FOO`.